# Drawing regions around XY points

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a list of XY points and I would like to draw/plot/graph a region around each point to visually display boundaries where the closest point is.

I began playing around on online GeoGebra graphing calculator to get a bit of idea what I'm after. [Here is a screenshot of what I started working out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyJyW.png)
I drew the regions manually by using the included Tools to find the Perpendicular Bisector of neighbouring point pairs and then drawing a Polygon region around each point where the Perpendicular Bisectors intersect.

As per the screenshot, I only have managed to draw about 34 regions (I have over 300 points and increasing), where the GeoGebra interface becomes very slow and tedious to use (*I assume*) due to the large number of points, lines and shapes being displayed.

**What I'm asking is...** Is something like this able to be accomplished in other ways such as a function to calculate the regions, maybe using a different type of graph/chart or possibly even a better program/app to use? Possibly I'm barking up the wrong tree...

Other thoughts:

- Possibly use a heatmap chart but I am unsure how to get the definite boundaries instead of "fuzzy" gradients.
- The points would not have to be labelled.
- Also, [here is the link to the GeoGebra graph](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/f9fxcgen) I'm working on.
- Possibly I should be looking for a mapping solution, to find/display the regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've discovered [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)! They are natively supported by GeoGebra's [Voronoi()](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Voronoi_Command) command. The Wikipedia article also links to efficient algorithms that may be implemented in other programs.